# Call to a member function getName() on a non-object- Error On Index Page, Runs At Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, blocks

My Problem might simple, but I am not getting where exactly problem is.

I have created on custom block under local cood pool. then extends the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` method, I have also created on phtml page under `frontend > page > html`.

My code works perfect when I click on product page. But when I move to index page It gives me error,

> Call to a member function getName() on a non-object-

Please refer following code and give me some suggestions.

### Block

```
class Kultureshop_Page_Block_Html_Custom extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

    protected $_crumbs = null;
    protected $_cacheKeyInfo = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/custom.phtml');
    }
      public function getProduct()
       {

        if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) 
          { 
           $product =   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
            Mage::register('product', $product);
          }
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }
}
```

### phtml

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
 <div class="">
 <h1><b>   <?php echo($_product->getName()); ?> By <?php echo($_product->getArtist()); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When entering the index page, there is neither a registry entry available nor a product ID passed to your custom block.

On the product page, the current product is registered via `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProduct()`, so it works fine there.

On the index page, you need to pass in a product ID explicitly when creating your custom block. There are multiple options to do so, depending on how you declare/create the block.

Comment: Thanks Could you plz explain how?

Comment: I will not cover all options. If you update your question to include _how_ your block gets created (layout xml, inline, …) then I will update my answer accordingly.